# Add rewrite location with Puppet / Nginx provisionner

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting, nginx, vagrant, puppet

I'd like to use this rule in Nginx config file :

```
location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}
```

(this rule is used for Symfony framework).
I used puphpet site to generate vagrant files and I modified default.pp to change the configuration of Nginx Vhost
I add something like that to create this rewrite rule :

```
nginx::resource::location { "${server_name}-rewrite":
    location        => '@rewriteapp',
    www_root        => $www_root,
    proxy           => undef,
    rewrite         => '^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;'
}
```

But I get the following error :
`Invalid parameter rewrite at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/manifests/default.pp:267 on node packer-virtualbox.vagrantup.com`

Is there a way to add rewrite rule to Nginx vhost config with Puppet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that rewrite is not a valid option in the nginx puppet module.

You need to use either `location_cfg_append` or `location_custom_cfg`

I dont have puppet setup at the moment to test but I think the syntax you need will be something like this:

```
nginx::resource::location { "${server_name}-rewrite":
    location            => '@rewriteapp',
    www_root            => $www_root,
    proxy               => undef,
    location_cfg_append => {
        'rewrite' => '^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;'
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to generate a correct config file for Symfony, because Puppet add paramters automatically, which I don't want (like index, for example). The solution I found is to add a post-install script that copy Nginx conf file and restart Nginx. It works fine and is much simpler for me.